# Do you get bonus points at the end or during play for these quest rewards?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

With the exception of Larissa Neathal, all Lords of Waterdeep give a bonus for completed quests if they are of a certain type. These points are scored at the end of the game - in part because your Lord is hidden.

There's also several Plot Quests that reward you with a bonus for completing certain types of quests. For instance:

> **Quell Mercenary Uprising**
>
> ---
>
> Reward: 8 VP
> Whenever you complete a Warfare quest, you score 2 VP

Is this bonus added at the end, also applying to each Warfare quest you've completed before? Or is this quest popped up open next to your tavern to provide the bonus for every Warfare quest completed from then on? And, if the second interpretation is the right one, would this quest qualify for its own bonus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Whenever" infers present tense, you score 2 VP at the exact time you complete a Warfare quest happens.

If it were to refer to end of game or count anything retrospectively then that would have been clearly stated.

I don't think the card would qualify for its own bonus.  The rules say.

> To complete a Quest, remove the required Adventurers and Gold from
> your Tavern. Return those tokens to the supply. Then collect the
> specified reward.

"Then collect" happens after the mission was completed.  not during.

> When you complete a Plot Quest, place its card face up near your
> player mat to remind you of the ongoing effect.

So "Whenever you complete a Warfare quest, you score 2 VP" is an ongoing affect.  It's usually in games for this to mean from now on.  if it applied to itself and all retrospective missions it should state that clearly.